# Replace certain Child value if doesn't contain certain string? or Rewrite XPATH query? Website scrape

Tags: php, dom, web-scraping, xpath

Preface: This is the first XPath and DOM script I have ever worked on.

The following code works, to a point.

If the child->nodevalue, which should be price, is empty it throws off the rest of the elements and it just snowballs from there. I have spent hours reading, rewriting and can't come up with a way to fix it.

I am at the point where I think my XPath query could be the issue because I am out of ideas on how to test that is the right child value.

The Content I am scraping  looks like this(Actually it looks nothing like this there are 148 lines of HTML for each product but these are the relevant ones):

```
<div class="some really long class name">
    <h2 class="second class">
        <a class="a-link-normal s-no-outline" href="TheURLINeed.php">
            <span class="a-size-base-plus a-color-base a-text-normal">
                The Title I Need
            </span>
        </a>
    </h2>
    <span class="a-offscreen">
      $1,000,000
    </span>
</div>
```

Here is the code I am using.

```
    $html =file_get_contents('http://localhost:8888/scraper/source.html');

    $doc = new \DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($html);
    $xpath = new \DOMXpath($doc);
    $xpath->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;

    $nodes= $xpath->query("//a[@class = 'a-link-normal s-no-outline'] | //span[@class = 'a-size-base-plus a-color-base a-text-normal'] | //span[@class = 'a-price']");

    $data =[];
    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
        $url =  $node->getAttribute('href');
        if(trim($url,"\xc2\xa0 \n \t \r") != ''){
            array_push($data,$url);
        }
        foreach ($node->childNodes as $child) {
            if (trim($child->nodeValue, "\xc2\xa0 \n \t \r") != '') {
                array_push($data, $child->nodeValue);
            }
        }
    }
    $chunks = (array_chunk($data, 4));

    foreach($chunks as $chunk) {
        $newarray = [
            'url' => $chunk[0],
            'title' => $chunk[1],
            'todaysprice' => $chunk[2],
            'hiddenprice' => $chunk[3]
            ];

    echo '<p>' . $newarray['url'] . '<br>' . $newarray['title'] . '<br>' .                 
    $newarray['todaysprice'] . '</p>';
}
```

Outputs:

```
URL
Title
Price

URL
Title
Price

URL
Title
URL.   <---- "Price was missing so it used the next child node value and now everything from here down is wrong."

Title
Price
URL
```

I am aware this code is FAR from the right but I had to start somewhere.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add an example where the price is missing and the exact output expected in both cases?

Comment: It is there, under output, see the bottom section where it says PRICE WAS MISSING so it used the next child. and product without a price just leave the span a-offscreen empty.

Comment: I saw that; I'm referring to an example of input (that is, another `<div>` element) with a missing price. I would be useful to know what it looks like.

Comment: They just leave the <span class="a-offscreen"> out of the html completely.

Comment: And I think that is why I need to  change my query... pull the contents of the surrounding div, in the example, check for the span containing price and if it isn't there skip to the next one.... I think! Like I said I am VERY new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are probably looking for something like the below. For the sake of simplicty, I skipped the array building parts, and just echoed the target data.

So assume your html looks like the one below:

```
$html = '
<body>
<div class="some really long class name">
    <h2 class="second class">
        <a class="a-link-normal s-no-outline" href="TheURLINeed.php">
            <span class="a-size-base-plus a-color-base a-text-normal">
                The Title I Need
            </span>
        </a>
    </h2>
    <span class="a-offscreen">
      $1,000,000
    </span>
</div>
<div class="some really long class name">
    <h2 class="second class">
        <a class="a-link-normal s-no-outline" href="TheURLINeed2.php">
            <span class="a-size-base-plus a-color-base a-text-normal">
                The other Title I Need
            </span>
        </a>
    </h2>
   
</div>
<div class="some really long class name">
    <h2 class="second class">
        <a class="a-link-normal s-no-outline" href="TheURLINeed3.php">
            <span class="a-size-base-plus a-color-base a-text-normal">
                The Final Title I Need
            </span>
        </a>
    </h2>
    <span class="a-offscreen">
      $2,000,000
    </span>
</div>
</body>
';
```

Try this:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$data = $xpath->query('//h2[@class="second class"]');

foreach($data as $datum){
    echo trim($xpath->query('.//a/@href',$datum)[0]->nodeValue),"\r\n";
    echo trim($xpath->query('.//a/span',$datum)[0]->nodeValue),"\r\n";
    #$price = $xpath->query('./following-sibling::span',$datum);
    #EDITED
    $price = $xpath->query('./following-sibling::span[@class="a-offscreen"]',$datum);
    if ($price->length>0) {
    echo trim($price[0]->nodeValue), "\r\n";
} else {
    echo("No Price"),"\r\n";
    
}
   
echo "\r\n";
};
```

Output:

```
TheURLINeed.php
The Title I Need
$1,000,000

TheURLINeed2.php
The other Title I Need
No Price

TheURLINeed3.php
The Final Title I Need
$2,000,000
```

Comment: OMG sooooo close!!!! Can I use a class to get the price as there are a couple empty spans before the actual price... I didn't think that would be important so I left them out, didn't know about the sibling thing....

Comment: @MelissaBean Yes, you can. See line marked EDITED.

Comment: Okay I think I can get it from here... It still comes back empty but there are so many lines of code to go through I am starting to think I missed something somewhere in between. 148 lines for 8 lines of text....argh! BTW is following-sibling chainable? for instance ./following-sibling/following-sibling::? I still have another page to parse after this one... If I live that long and still have any hair left.

Comment: @MelissaBean Yes, following-sibling is chainable, but I wouldn't abuse it too much... The code does work with the sample html in the answer, so there must be something in the actual html that is different and causes the wrong output.

Comment: There was... I found 2 div tags I missed when formatting it into some thing readable. I actually had to rewrite the original query and start with the outer most div and grab the child nodes by class from within that div block. It works 100% now and I did upvote your answer as it lead me down the right path to a perfect end! Thank you!!

Comment: You got it! Thanks again!